# CLGeocoder geocodeAddressString not working with partial place names (i.e. 'Lond' doesn't show 'London')

Tags: ios, location, geocode, clgeocoder, apple-maps

I'm trying to use Apple's CLGeocoder to search for a place based on a string and get the latitude/longitude of it.  I'm using an instant feedback system, so as you type the address in, suggestions are made beneath the search field from which a selection can be made from, using this function:

```
(void)geocodeAddressString:(NSString *)addressString completionHandler:(CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)completionHandler
```

however, it seems to search for each space-separated token in its exact form as opposed to as a part of another word.  For example, if I search for 'Lond', I get "Lond, Sheopur, Madhya Pradesh, India" instead of "London".

How can I make CLGeocoder work with partial place names and return 'London' for the string 'Lond'?

Thanks,